# PointerLock with dart

Tags: dart, dart-html, pointerlock

Is there a way to lock the cursor with dart that works on Firefox and Chrome?
I tried:

```dart
void lock(event)
{    
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.requestPointerLock();
}
```

in a mousedown-event listener

```dart
 document.addEventListener('mousedown', lock, false);
```

I also tried

```dart
renderer.canvas.requestPointerLock();
```

where renderer is a WebGLRenderer from the three.dart package.
The problem is this works only in Chromium.
I looked up the following crossbrowser-solution for js, but this doesn't work in dart.

```dart
canvas.requestPointerLock = canvas.requestPointerLock ||
                 canvas.mozRequestPointerLock ||
                 canvas.webkitRequestPointerLock;
```

Is there a way to do the pointer lock in dart, or do I need to find a way to execute the javascript above from dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue for this https://dartbug.com/4463

I think the problem in your code code using prefixes is that `canvas.requestPointerLock`, `canvas.mozRequestPointerLock`, `canvas.webkitRequestPointerLock` don't return `false` if they don't exist (or `true` if it does). You have to get the current browser by other means and then call the prefixed method.

Comment: Thanks! Also I had a problem because dart didn't recognize the mozRequestPointerLock and webkitRequestPointerLock attributes. So I added a javascript that locks the pointer.